# Do I need to call DestroyIcon if I made it with LoadIconWithScaleDown?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm creating icons in my app using [`LoadIconWithScaleDown()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775703%28VS.85%29.aspx).  I also fall back to [`CreateIconFromResourceEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648061%28VS.85%29.aspx) if the preferred function is not available.

The documentation for [`DestroyIcon()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648063%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) states:

> It is only necessary to call
>   DestroyIcon for icons and cursors
>   created with the following functions:
>   CreateIconFromResourceEx (if called
>   without the LR_SHARED flag),
>   CreateIconIndirect, and CopyIcon. Do
>   not use this function to destroy a
>   shared icon. A shared icon is valid as
>   long as the module from which it was
>   loaded remains in memory. The
>   following functions obtain a shared
>   icon.
>
> - **LoadIcon**
> - **LoadImage** (if you use the LR_SHARED flag)
> - **CopyImage** (if you use
>     the LR_COPYRETURNORG flag and the
>     hImage parameter is a shared icon)
> - **CreateIconFromResource**
> - **CreateIconFromResourceEx** (if you use
>     the LR_SHARED flag)

Note: I'm not passing `LR_SHARED` to `CreateIconFromResourceEx()`; perhaps I should.

What I would like to know is, do I need to call `DestroyIcon()` for the icons made with `LoadIconWithScaleDown()`?

Comment: Not documented, painful.  I would have to vote Yes.  Simply because the function would be unusable otherwise.  There are odds that DestroyIcon returns FALSE when the icon is actually shared so don't bomb that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say yes, since the HICON you're getting back does not seem to be shared according to the documentation. Windows obviously does not want you to destroy icons whose handles are shared, but that isn't the case here, and if you fallback to another function that takes LR_SHARED but you're not passing the flag, then that means your process owns the icon handle and you should destroy it when you're done using it.

Comment: Thanks. This was what my intuition told me too. When does windows share icons? And with whom or what?

Comment: The icons that appear on message boxes (warning, error, exclamation, etc) for example, are shared. You can obtain a handle to those and use them in places other than a default message box.

Comment: and icons can be passed to other processes?

Comment: Passing a handle cross-process is trickier. It's been a while since I've done shell development but if these are shared icons we're talking about anyway, why not just obtain the handle in the other process directly?

Comment: I'm not actually doing any cross-process stuff in my app, I'm just trying to improve my knowledge!

Comment: Ah :) You might want to Google 'windows pass handle cross process' or something like that to get an idea of what that involves. Like I said, it's been a while since I've done much Win32 coding.

Comment: @David - When `LR_SHARED` is specified to load a system icon the returned handle is valid system-wise (for similar size/color). Other than that, I don't think a resource handle could be passed cross-process.

Comment: Thanks for this all. My experiments back up the theory that DestroyIcon needs to be called. Would be nice for the documentation to catch up!